# Need an efficient way to support ranking mechanism in Salesforce

Tags: trigger, batch, scheduled-apex, case

On the case object, i have a numeric score field which gets populated using before insert/update trigger and based on few fields selected on case. Now the requirement is to give a rank number to each Case record which implicitly changes based on the score field which keeps on updating. Now the concern is change in score for 1 case record, might update the ranking for all the case records in the system. Doing this thing dynamically on change of any case record score would might lead into governor limits  issue depending on the number of DML operation done.
Thought of running a scheduler say once or twice a day which would renumber the ranking in bulk but would like to hear from the audience, if there is any optimum approach other than scheduler to achieve solution to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Would a formula field or workflow rule work? Also, what considerations are there that updating one case would cascade to all case records?

Comment: If the score on a particular case record changes, then accordingly, the system should compare score for all the case records again and renumber the ranking. I dont think formulae or workflow work here as need to revist all the case records score to renumber or re rank them again.

Comment: As much as I understand the use case, I am not sure if this is really a scalable idea. Imagine down the line you end up having  10k+ cases, how relevant would a rank on 7777st case be? Or on any case which is an year old and closed? That being said if the ranking is based on the score you have then would be an option to just "sort" them on that field without actually assigning a number to it?

Comment: @Sai : Yes you are correct, I might not need the older data as of now. I thought of the sortign option as well but the requriement is to report on ranking and showing the numbers on standard list views of Salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a hard requirement that you must show the ranking number in standard list views, and that number must be ordinal (i.e. 1, 2, 3), and you have a record count that will exceed standard governor limits then you have no choice: you must use a batch job. It's clear to see why, since a record whose score moves from last to first will force a renumbering of every record in the system.

You can achieve an estimated number before the batch job runs by doing something like `[select Rank__c from Case where Score__c <= :currentScore order by Rank__c desc limit 1]` and assigning that Rank to the current object: this will cause objects with duplicate ranks until the next batch run, but that's often much better than no rank at all.

If you can live with a percentile score of something like 0-100, where 100 is highest and 0 is lowest, there is an O(1) approach that I've used in big data systems in the past.

In a custom setting object, you keep 11 (or more for higher accuracy) histogram-type scores of the object at each decile: this will look something like, say, 0, 500, 590, 650, up to field 11 which will hold the score of the highest scoring object in your system. You use a batch job to update these deciles periodically (I usually do once per day or week in big systems).

Then, when a score is updated on a single object, you can get a pretty accurate estimate of its percentile score by finding the decile its score falls within, and using a linear fit to estimate its percentile score. In the above case, if an object had a score of 200, you would give it a percentile score as 4/100, since it's 40% along the lowest decile (0-500). A score of, say, 620 would return a percentile score of 25/100 since that's halfway between the 20% and 30% decile scores. If an object exceeds the highest decile, or falls below the lowest, you update the decile histogram accordingly and rank it a 100 or 0 accordingly.

It doesn't strictly meet your requirements for an ordinal ranking, but it achieves a similar end in O(1) and also doesn't ever need a full-system re-ranking if your scores maintain a somewhat consistent distribution and accuracy isn't vital.